# How to use pull to refresh on a list view on windows phone in xamarin

Tags: listview, c#-4.0, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

## The Question

The question is simple, how can we use the pull to refresh functionality of the Xamarin Forms ListView control ***correctly*** on the Windows Phone platform?

The definition of ***correctly***: If the total combined height of all list items is smaller than the ListView (because it fills its container) the pull to refresh does not work.It works fine however on iOS and Android.

## Background

### What the manual says

According to the [manual](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/#Pull_to_Refresh), it shouldn't even work in our Windows Phone 8.1 silverlight application as the following extract shows. This implies we are not even using Windows Phone 8.1...

> Note that as of Xamarin.Forms 1.4.3, pull-to-refresh is not supported
>   on Windows Phone 8.1. On Windows phone 8, pull-to-refresh is not a
>   native platform feature, so an implementation of pull-to-refresh is
>   provided by Xamarin.Forms. Finally, be aware that pull-to-refresh will
>   not work on Windows Phone if all elements in the list can fit on the
>   screen (in other words, if vertical scrolling isn't required).

### What we tried/propose

We propose that a possible solution would involve shrinking the `ListView` `HeightRequest` property to one less than calculated height of all the items and padding it contains. But how could you calculate the height of all the items if the `RowHeight` property is always -1 and the item heights can change because of our custom `DataTemplate`?

As an alternative, give we can't solve this problem, we will add a refresh toolbar item. This will allow the user to pull to refresh if